# changing background of active menu item

Tags: css, hover, stylesheet

i am creating simple side menu, such that when the user hover on item background color change and when he clicks on it the hover effect should be maintained until user clicks other item

my code:

```
 ul#nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    -moz-appearance: menubar;
        -webkit-appearance: menubar;
    background-position: left;
    font-size: larger;
}

.mmenu{ width: 190px;
       position: fixed;
}
.mmenu a{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
}

.mmenu a:hover{ color: white;
background-color: #003366;
font-style: oblique;
border-top: 0px outset #003366;
border-bottom: 0px inset #003366;
border-right:0px outset #003366;
border-left: 0px inset ;
}
```

the hover effect is working fine, however the style is not maintained when i click any item, i tried active, visited but no luck. anyone knows where is the problem?

html

```
<div id="nav" class="mmenu" style="border: 2px double #f2f2f2; left: 25px; width: 200px; border-radius: 6px;">
                            <ul type="none">        
                                        <li><a  href="another example.php">Messages</a></li>
                                        <li><a  href= "example.php">My Conferences</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

Comment: you cannot handle click events via css, you should use js/jquery instead

Comment: You will need some javascript,Do you still want to know the solution

Comment: Once link is clicked you should manually add a style to this link, to show that this item is active now.

Comment: @Onheiron - I think the OP is referring to the :active pseudo-class.

Comment: active can't work for your purpose. active means as long as the element is clicked. As soon as you release the mouse button, your element is not active anymore.

Comment: Can you provide the html part also? Or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @AnkitGautam, yes sure, the logic should be click function for links and then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the attribute

```
Onclick="this.style.background='#003366'"
```

to the menu item (".mmenu a")

Comment: when you know it can't be done with css then what will you do and the OP is not allergic to one line of js

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a navigation item, is it linking to another page? In this case, you need to add a class to navigation items and style with the class.

```
<style>
body.page-name-1 #nav li.page-name-1 a, body.page-name-2 #nav li.page-name-2 a
{
    background-color: #003366;
}
</style>

<body class='<?php echo $page_name ?>'> 
<!-- If you are using PHP, and every page has a $page_name -->
<div id='nav' class='mmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='page-name-1' ><a href="another example.php">Messages</a></li>
<li class='page-name-2' ><a href= "example.php">My Conferences</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
</body>
```